# To what extent does DynamicExpression.Parse recognise C# symbols?

Tags: c#, dynamic

Given a string :  "5.2m*5.7m"
and return type being Decimal;
and calling

```
`System.Linq.Dynamic.DynamicExpression.Parse(returnType, expression);`
```

will give a syntax error regarding the character on position which is 'm';
After a bit of testing the same applies to 'd';
To give a bit of context,the reason to use m is to avoid another error which is multiplication of double*decimal as it will interpret a floating point value as double by default.

My question is: Why does this happen? and what would be the best scenario of solving the double*decimal problem? cast by means of (decimal)5.7 the value I know to be decimal or use Convert.ToDecimal(5.7)?How much really does parse() know?(I didn't find documentation on msdn or the like)

Comment: According to the documentation (https://github.com/kahanu/System.Linq.Dynamic/wiki/Dynamic-Expressions#literals), does not support those literal type suffixes like "d", "m", etc. However, a real number literal (see the documentation link again) implicitely converts to a `decimal` value (if the value can be represented as a decimal). So you should be fine just parsing `"5.2*5.7"` with a `decimal` return type. I base my suggestion only on the given documentation, and I don't know your actual real problem in your code, so i am aware my suggestion might perhaps not be that helpful...

Comment: That is useful info,thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is: Why does this happen?

This happens because `DynamicExpression` uses a custom-built expression parser. It is made to resemble C# but it is not C#. Not everything that is valid in C# will work, and some things that are valid in C# work differently.

> and what would be the best scenario of solving the double*decimal problem? cast by means of (decimal)5.7 the value I know to be decimal or use Convert.ToDecimal(5.7)?

Cast, but not using this syntax. The syntax to use is `type(expr)`, not `(type)expr`, see below.

> How much really does parse() know?(I didn't find documentation on msdn or the like)

A copy of the original documentation appears to be available at http://ak-dynamic-linq.azurewebsites.net/GettingStarted. I have not verified that the whole document is unmodified, but I have compared the below to the original documentation.

To quote:

> The expression language permits explicit conversions using the syntax `type(expr)` or `type"string"`, where *type* is a type name optionally followed by `?` and *expr* is an expression or *string* is a string literal. This syntax may be used to perform the following conversions:
>
> - Between two types provided `Type.IsAssignableFrom` is true in one or both directions.
> - Between two types provided one or both are interface types.
> - Between the nullable and non-nullable forms of any value type.
> - Between string and any type that have static TryParse method.
> - Between any two types belonging to the set consisting of `SByte`, `Byte`, `Int16`, `UInt16`, `Int32`, `UInt32`, `Int64`, `UInt64`, `Decimal`, `Single`, `Double`, `Char`, any *enum* type, as well as the *nullable* forms of those types.

Comment: How do I mark this answer as The answer?Upvoting doesnt seem to work.

Comment: @NichitaCebotari Glad it helped. You should see an empty check mark below the upvote and downvote buttons, you can click that to accept or unaccept answers.